# How to pass arguments in function in onclick event in jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery

I changed function with argument in onclick event in AJAX, but there is some mistake. It's not working. What mistake I have done?

```
function changeStatus(pid,status,table)
{
$.ajax({
    url:'view/ajax_change_status.php?pid='+pid+'&status='+status+'&table='+table,
    type:'GET',
    cache:false,
    success:function(result)
    {
        $('.status_'+pid).html(result);
        if(result=='Enabled')
        {
            var newStatus=1;
        }
        else
        {
            var newStatus=0;
        }
        $('.status_'+pid).attr("onclick",'return changeStatus('+pid+','+newStatus+','+table+')');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling this function. you could show us that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this

```
$('.status_'+pid).attr("onclick",'return changeStatus('+pid+','+newStatus+','+table+')');
```

to

```
$('.status_'+pid).attr("onclick",'return changeStatus(\''+pid+'\',\''+newStatus+'\',\''+table+'\')');
```

And also make sure the url of the php file is correct. I'm suggesting you to use absolute paths instead of relative ones:

`/view/ajax_change_status.php`

Comment: Welcome! Good luck with your project! :)